# Custom dataLabels SVG doesn't appear in exporting png or pdf highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have inverted column chart and at the end of each data point, I set custom SVG icon along with some text

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    pointWidth: 1,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      inside: false,
      crop: false,
      overflow: 'none',
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return `
           <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; cursor: pointer">
            <img  class="${this.point.className}-icon" src="./assets/${this.point.className}.svg" alt=${this.point.className}>
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; margin-left: 15px; ">
              <span style="color:#4E4E4E">${this.point.name}</span>
              <span style="color:#9E9E9E">Value: ${this.point.y}</span>
              </div>
           </div>
            }
          },
        },
      }
```

[image]

When I try to download graph as PNG, then no SVG icon was displayed. Then I added

```
exporting: {
        allowHTML: true,
        ...
},
```

And the result(exporting as PNG) was
[image]

I tried to set `<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94........"` and then image was rendering on the screen, but dataLabels are no longer in one line and icons looks way too small. Although I think I could apply some styling, the issue here is that ideally I'd like to import svg's as files from assets rather than converting all of them into base64 strings.
[image]

And last but not least - exporting graph as PDF (with various iterations of exporting properties from above) outputs me this:
[image]

So, has anyone encountered this problem:

- Can I export SVG dataLabels that are not in base64 but in separate folder as files?
- How to style exported dataLabels so they are displayed inline without breaking into multiple lines?
- Why exporting as PDF doesn't even render any icons, while PNG does?

I also tried to play around with `chart.events.exportData` but no success whatsoever.

Comment: Please add a live demo for the problem. You could check if using the lollipop series will help as that series type looks more like the chart you need: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/lollipop The missing images might be caused by not being loaded on the export server, but I will be more certain after checking a live demo.

Comment: @KacperMadej here's working demo - https://jsfiddle.net/hcozrgvm/1/ . Although this works on fiddle, but it doesn't work on my project. The environment that I'm using is in Angular. So, I have highcharts v6.0.7 and highcharts-angular v1.0.2.
For me - when I download as PDF, the icons are still not visible :/

I agree - for my current chart looks like I need a lollipop chart, but that requires me to updating the package, but then a few other charts are breaking, so it's kind of a rabbit hole from there

Comment: If exporting as PNG does include images, but not for PDFs, does this mean that these 2 features are using different export server?

Comment: Updating Highcharts from v6 to v7 (v7.1.1 in my case) solved the issue!

Comment: Happy to hear that this worked out for you. If updating fixes the problem then it's highly probable that this was a bug that was fixed in between the version and the Highcharts technical support solution will be to update the library.

Comment: Hi there, I've implemented your solution with base64 encoded SVGs as icons, but the 'Export SVG' function of Highcharts appears to be producing a malformed SVG which cannot be viewed. The example you've posted above seems to suffer from the same issue. Did you ever get to the bottom of this? Cheers!